# jQuery Sorting multidimensional array on second value

Tags: jquery, sorting

> I have an multidimensional array having two values in it. I want to sort complete array on the basis of second value of the array. I attached the console output of the array.

```
$( "#code_list1 > li" ).each(function( index ) {
        var code = $("span.code", this).text(); 
        var c3 = $( this );
        var description = $("span.description", this).text();   
        code1_li[code]= [c3,description];

    })
  Now want to sort code1_li by second element of the array having index position 1
```

Comment: please insert the output as text, not as an image. Images aren't searchable or crawlable. You can edit your own answer to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

To sort an array based on an object's property's value that's a string (specifically here on your `description` property), do this:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
      var descA = a.description.toLowerCase();
      var descB = b.description.toLowerCase(); 
      return ((descA < descB) ? -1 : ((descA > descB) ? 1 : 0));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/2Lxmb48d/)